# Spritekit Disable Touch on Certain Area of View

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes

New coder here, I made a code for dragging/throwing an object and I wanted to know how to make it so that only part of the screen can be used for touch, i.e. only the bottom half of the screen can be touched. This is my gamescene code, and I'm using Swift 2.0.

```
import SpriteKit

var sprite = SKSpriteNode!()
var touchPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint()

var touching: Bool = false
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottle")
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2.0, y: self.size.height/2.0)
    self.addChild(sprite)
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -4.9)
    
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let sprite = StarNode.star(touch.locationInNode(self))
    touchPoint = location
    touching = true
   }

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    touchPoint = location
    
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    
    touching = false
    
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if touching {
        let dt:CGFloat = 1.0/5.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-sprite.position.x, dy:     touchPoint.y-sprite.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
   } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ignore touches in the top half of the screen. If so, you could add a check to `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` like so:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    guard location.y < self.frame.midY else {
        return
    }

    let sprite = StarNode.star(touch.locationInNode(self))
    touchPoint = location
    touching = true
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    guard location.y < self.frame.midY else {
        // You might want set touching to false here, depends on the rest of your code
        return
    }


    touchPoint = location
}
```

The new code I added checks that the Y position of the touch is less than half the height of the scene, assuming the origin is at the bottom left. If the check fails, the function exits - you might want to add some code to cancel touch actions there.
If you'd like a certain portion of the screen to be untouchable, you could make a `CGRect` and check that the touch location is always outside the rect, e.g:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let untouchableArea = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 150)

    guard !untouchableArea.contains(location) else {
        return
    }    
    // Could do something similar in touchesMoved to guard against moving into the untouchable area
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But I have another problem. I want to make it so that when the object was dragged from the touch enabled area to to disabled, it will release on its own even if you are still touching. How would I go about with this? Currently if you keep holding down the object will stay at the border and only fall if released.

Comment: @shadokyr Looking at your code, I think you'd want to call the same code in your `touchesEnded` function, which is `touching = false`, when the object is dragged into the disabled area. So in the `guard` statement in `touchesMoved:`, on the line before `return`, try putting `touching = false`, which should trigger the same behaviour as lifting the finger.

Answer (score 0):

Alessandro Ornano's response will work - analyzing the location of the touch.

Another approach is to use a "touch blocker".  Since SpriteKit only registers the topmost touch, you could place a SKSpriteNode that uses the UIColor.clear color and set its isUserInteractionEnabled to true and its z position high enough that it's above the other touchable content.  This will make a transparent region that "eats" touches on it.

(A handy debugging / visualization technique for this is to, during development, give it a faint transparent color instead of it being completely clear, so you can see the area affected and whether any sprites have snuck up above the blocking area.)

This has the advantage of being simpler, and making it easy to turn the functionality off and on or easily change the affected area.  But it also has some differences from Alessandro's approach.  For instance, it doesn't block drags that would go up into its area; once the drag is established outside the area of the touch blocker, it will continue to receive touchesMoved events even if you drag your finger over the touch blocker's area.  Either method would work.  You just need to choose the one that works best for your particular needs.

Comment: Thank you to having quoted me, but the answer was of @nanothread59